# Vectorize image from pen drawing

Tags: image-editing, vector-graphics

I have some pen drawing (basically there are three words) as follows:
[image]

Is there any tool I could use so that I can make this three words as vectorized images?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the image cleaned up and transparent?

You could do that with any number of the Abode tools. Illustrator could Live Trace the edges and Photoshop has a number of ways that could do it. e.g. Manually Pen Tool the outline, increase the contrast and magic wand then convert to vector.

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) could do it in a very similar fashion to Photoshop.

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) could also do it.

So yes, there are tools that you can use to vectorise those words.